# first_or_create undefined in Rails 3.0.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to start using the function first_or_create, which I found in the ActiveRecord API and in the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object . However, Rails pretends not to recognize this function:

```
irb(main):017:0> EoWord.where("id = 110")
=> [#<EoWord id: 110, word: "abatino", wordtype: "substantivo", topic: "pregado, homo">]
irb(main):018:0> EoWord.where("word = 'abatino'").first_or_create
NoMethodError: undefined method `first_or_create' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1ccf578>
        from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:374:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):18
        from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Rails 3.0.7 under Windows. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, this method is undefined in Rails 3.0.7.

This method only exists in Rails 3.2.1, according to [APIDock's documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create). You'll need to upgrade your version of Rails to get it.

Comment: Same thing I was going to say. :)  It's a one line method, if you are stuck on rails 3.0.7 for some reason and want to use it.

Comment: Thank you! At the top of the guide page it says "This Guide is based on Rails 3.0. Some of the code shown here will not work in other versions of Rails." so I didn't consider that it might be the wrong version of Rails. Anyway, I upgraded and it works.